# Identification of only a part of an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-detection, vlfeat

I want to identify only this marked part in my image. (marked in red)
It should be a scale and translation invariant matching algorithm. Which is the best method I can use?

Will the SIFT method be useful here? As I have observed, it outputs many points. I want only this predefined part to be identified always. Maybe as a blob, or the centroid of this part.

[image]

*Edit*: I am trying to use SIFT from [VLFeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/sift.html#tut.sift.match). This is the code I am using:

```
Ia = imread ('Img_1.bmp') ;     % Img_1 is the entire wheel's image
Ib = imread ('Img_2.png') ;     % Img_2 is a small image containing only the part I want to identify in all images.
Ia = im2single(rgb2gray(Ia)) ;
Ib = im2single(rgb2gray(Ib)) ;
[fa, da] = vl_sift(Ia) ;
[fb, db] = vl_sift(Ib) ;
[matches, scores] = vl_ubcmatch(da, db) ;
```

After this, how can I view the matched images? As it is shown on the website?

Also, will this method serve my purpose of identifying only the small notch?

How should I proceed after this?

Comment: Try with SIFT, but obtain points for SIFT only of that part of the image, and then match with points computed for the whole image.

Comment: Well, this notch can lie anywhere on the rim. If it is rotated along the rim's plane, it can also come on top. How can I identify which part to apply SIFT on?

Comment: You need to have 1 "truth" notch. Apply SIFT to just that "truth".  Then, apply SIFT for the whole image in the other images and match the found points.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any other kind of algorithm in mind apart from SIFT?

Comment: Also, could you please expand a little more? I got an idea of what you're saying, but I'm unable to find relevant key-words and required literature for its implementation on MATLAB.

Comment: What you wanat to do is very well explained in OPENCV, as its widely used for that porpose. Here there is a very good example of how to do it: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html . Ofcourse, you would need to do the same in Matlab, wich may not be straigthforward

Comment: search for "feature matching" as keywords. Tehre is some quite nice examples im matlab (I didnt know!). Have a look: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/matchfeatures.html?refresh=true

Comment: I am unable to find any source codes for this. Are you aware of any working codes?

Comment: Not for Matlab, but I know that there is a full example implemented in C++ in openCV examples and tutorials.

Comment: Yea, I too came across a few in C++. Anyway, thanks!